# What's the most efficient way of intersecting to collections in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, collections, performance

I'm new in python, sorry if there's anything wrong.

I'd like to intersect several collections (20 o 30) with a big amount of elements in them.

I've been reading and know that Sets are similar to hashtables (work with the same principle). 
Sets has the intersect method, i've been trying it and works really fine.

But, would like to have an experienced opinion.

What would you do?

The problem again. 20 or 30 collections (can be set, the elements are not repeated) and want to make intersection of them. Don't think how the collections are created (i.e. the insertion doesn't matters)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with using sets? The built-in data structures in python are generally very efficient. Unless your collections are large enough that you're running out of memory, a `set` seems to be exactly what you need, in this case...

Comment: There's nothing wrong!!! Actually, that's the way i'm doing it. But I honestly don't know it it's the best way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = set1.intersection(set2, set3, set4, ...)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: I wonder, is `set1.intersection(sorted((set2, set3, ...), key=len))` better in most practical situations? Or alternatively just pick out the smallest to do first rather than fully sorting.

Comment: you are free to perform this kind of optimization on the application level

Comment: Sure, and if we cared enough we could check whether a particular Python implementation already does anything of the kind.

Comment: @Steve, good point! It's like query optimization and Relational Algebra. Does Set.intersection do it?